# Get "Component auth has not been registered yet" when using Firebase authentication from Angular app

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm trying to add authentication to my Angular/Firebase app. I got it working no-problem in a small demo app, but when I try to add it to my real Angular application, I get "Component auth has not been registered yet" console errors in the browser.

To narrow the issue down, I copied this minimal authentication component from the Firebase "angularfire" samples ():

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import firebase from '@firebase/app-compat';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { trace } from '@angular/fire/compat/performance';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth',
  template: `
    <p>
      Auth!
      {{ (auth.user | async)?.uid | json }}
      {{ (auth.credential | async)?.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser | json }}
      <button (click)="login()" *ngIf="showLoginButton">Log in with Google</button>
      <button (click)="loginAnonymously()" *ngIf="showLoginButton">Log in anonymously</button>
      <button (click)="logout()" *ngIf="showLogoutButton">Log out</button>
    </p>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private readonly userDisposable: Subscription | undefined;

  showLoginButton = false;
  showLogoutButton = false;

  constructor(public readonly auth: AngularFireAuth, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: object) {
    if (!isPlatformServer(platformId)) {
      this.userDisposable = this.auth.authState.pipe(
        trace('auth'),
        map(u => !!u)
      ).subscribe(isLoggedIn => {
        this.showLoginButton = !isLoggedIn;
        this.showLogoutButton = isLoggedIn;
      });
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.userDisposable) {
      this.userDisposable.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  async login() {
    const user = await this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
    // TODO sign into offline app
  }

  async loginAnonymously() {
    const user = await this.auth.signInAnonymously();
    // TODO sign into offline app
  }

  logout() {
    this.auth.signOut();
    // TODO sign out of offline app
  }

}
```

The imports section of my app.module.ts looks like this (edited):

```js
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    ...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideFunctions(() => getFunctions()),
  ],
```

The console error that I'm seeing looks like this:

> zone.js:182 Uncaught Error: Component auth has not been registered yet
> at Provider.initialize (index.esm2017.js:232:19)
> at new Auth (index.esm2017.js:651:35)
> at Component.instance.INTERNAL.registerComponent.*firebase_component__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3*_.Component.setServiceProps.ActionCodeInfo.Operation.EMAIL_SIGNIN [as instanceFactory] (index.esm2017.js:969:16)
> at Provider.getOrInitializeService (index.esm2017.js:290:39)
> at Provider.getImmediate (index.esm2017.js:128:29)
> at FirebaseAppImpl._getService (index.esm2017.js:83:1)
> at FirebaseAppImpl.firebaseAppImpl. [as auth] (index.esm2017.js:291:1)
> at angular-fire-compat-auth.js:59:51
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:1)
> at Zone.run (zone.js:134:1)

I've examined the Authentication settings of my app in the Firebase console, and they're identical for what I have set in my demo app, which works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wew, that took hours and hours or work to narrow down the issue!

I finally figured out that the problem was that I had "@firebase/app" in my dependencies and that was causing the error. I'm guessing that it conflicted with the "@angular/fire" package, or something similar. I removed it, and Firebase authentication is now working in my app.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the same problem, but the answer above solved it. The specific procedure is as follows.

1. Delete `node_modules` and `package.lock.json`
2. Run `npm install`

Reference
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6019#issuecomment-1122783339

Answer (score 5):

If using yarn,

`yarn why firebase`

You may find you have two different firebase deps installed, one for angularfire, one direct dependency. You can do yarn resolutions to force only one, or remove the direct dependency to rely on the one angularfire brings in. Probably the latter option is best as yarn resolutions can get tricky.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer did not work for me but what did work was uninstalling @angular/fire and reinstalling

Comment: Thank you! Works also for me. I also had to remove `firebase` NPM package.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't undersstnad why, but removing and adding back @angular/fire works for me. By the way, the problem only affected the production builds. 'npm start' has been working fine all the while.
By the way, I am using yarn v3. No sure if it matters.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a permanant fix. I have to do it somewhat weekly. On May 12 2022, a new phenomenon: no error message at all, but page doesn't load. Same cure though.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had different versions of **firebase-app.js** and **firebase-auth.js** files.

For example:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-app.js";

import { getAuth } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-auth.js";
```

But got fixed when I used the same version

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-app.js";

import { getAuth } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-auth.js";
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into this issue today.

It's seem's that is because we have differents version of Firebase in dependencies.

To resolve this :

- first check which version you have : `npm ls @firebase/app`
- if you see different version like in the screenshot [result of command  npm ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzk4S.png)
  You can see that i've version @0.9.14 & @0.9.13

```bash
├─┬ @firebase/storage@0.11.2
│ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14
└─┬ firebase@9.23.0
  ├─┬ @firebase/analytics@0.10.0
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
  ├─┬ @firebase/app-check@0.8.0
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
  ├─┬ @firebase/app-compat@0.2.13
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.13
  ├── @firebase/app@0.9.13
  ├─┬ @firebase/auth@0.23.2
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
  ├─┬ @firebase/firestore@3.13.0
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
  ├─┬ @firebase/functions@0.10.0
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
  ├─┬ @firebase/installations@0.6.4
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
  ├─┬ @firebase/messaging@0.12.4
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
  ├─┬ @firebase/performance@0.6.4
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
  └─┬ @firebase/remote-config@0.4.4
    └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
```

- so update dependance of firebase and @firebase/storage to higher version solve this issue for me.

The points here is to align all firebase dependencies of your project

Answer (score 0):

for me, my problem was caused by using the following two conflicting packages:

> <s>"@types/firebase": "^3.2.1",</s>
>
> "firebase": "^9.12.0"

so after getting rid of `@types/firebase` and running `yarn install` that fixed it for me