# Getting "Component app-check has not been registered yet" when using Firebase with NextJS

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-app-check

I am trying to use Firebase App Check in my NextJS (`v13.1.1`) website, but when I try to initialize it, I get the following error `Error: Component app-check has not been registered yet`. I am trying to initialize it in `_app.js`:

```js
import firebase from '../firebase/clientApp'
const { initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaV3Provider } = require("firebase/app-check");
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  useEffect(() => {

    self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;

    const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(firebase, {
      provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY),
      isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true
    });

  }, []);

  return (
    <main>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  )
}
```

This is the `clientApp.js` file, where I initialize the firebase app:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default app;
```

I have taken a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71101900/12819433, but I do not have duplicate packages. I have `firebase` and `firebase-admin` installed, but I need both of them.

Comment: @ozenK I separated the App Check initalisation into a separate component with and loaded it before main Component in `_app.js`. Check my answer for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate component for App Check Initalisation:

```js
import firebase from "../firebase/clientApp";
import {initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaV3Provider} from "firebase/app-check";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function InitialiseAppCheck() {

    useEffect(() => {

        if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
            self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN;
        }
        const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(firebase, {
            provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY),
            isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true
        });
    },[]);
    
    return null;
}
```

Load the above component around your main component in `_app.js`:

```js
import '../styles/globals.css'
import InitialiseAppCheck from '../components/InitialiseAppCheck';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return (
    <main>
      <InitialiseAppCheck />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  )
}
```